# Make Jest setup wait until docker compose command is executed

Tags: typescript, docker-compose, jestjs, e2e

I have Jest E2E project configured for Nx Nest app. My goal is to run `docker compose up` for E2E testing and `docker compose down` after testing is over.

In `global-setup.ts`, I wrote:

```
/* eslint-disable */
var __TEARDOWN_MESSAGE__: string;

var os = require('os');

module.exports = async function () {
  // Start services that that the app needs to run (e.g. database, docker-compose, etc.).
  console.log('\nSetting up...\n');

  globalThis.execCmd = (cmd: string) => {
    const exec = require('child_process').exec;
    const command = exec(cmd, (err, stdOut, stdErr) => {
        if (err) {
            console.log(err);
            return;
        }

        console.log(stdOut);
    });

    return command;
  };

  const isWin = os.platform() === 'win32';
  const dockerComposeUpCmd = 'docker compose up';

  await globalThis.execCmd(dockerComposeUpCmd).on('exit', (code) => {
    console.log(`${command}: Finished with code ${code}`);
  });


  // Hint: Use `globalThis` to pass variables to global teardown.
  globalThis.__TEARDOWN_MESSAGE__ = '\nTearing down...\n';
};
```

The problem is that, when I run `npx nx e2e <e2e-project>`, all tests fail because of `Internal Server Error`, which happens because `docker compose up` is outran.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

I would highly recommend using https://pdmlab.github.io/docker-compose/ for this.

Then while having `docker-compose.yml` in the same directory as your `global-setup.ts` and `global-teardown.ts`, configure `global-setup.ts` like this:

```js
import * as path from 'path';
import * as compose from 'docker-compose';

/* eslint-disable */
var __TEARDOWN_MESSAGE__: string;
var __COMPOSE__: any;

module.exports = async function () {
  // Start services that the app needs to run (e.g. database, docker-compose, etc.).
  console.log('\nSetting up...');

  globalThis.__COMPOSE__ = compose;

  try {
    await globalThis.__COMPOSE__.upAll({
      cwd: path.join(__dirname),
      commandOptions: [['--build'], ['--force-recreate']],
      callback: (chunk: Buffer) => {
        console.log('job in progress: ', chunk.toString());
      },
    });

    console.log('Boot-up completed.');
  } catch (err) {
    console.log('Something went wrong during docker compose boot-up:', err.message);
  }

  // Hint: Use `globalThis` to pass variables to global teardown.
  globalThis.__TEARDOWN_MESSAGE__ = '\nTearing down...\n';
};
```

while `global-teardown.ts` like this:

```js
/* eslint-disable */

import path from 'path';

module.exports = async function () {
  // Put clean up logic here (e.g. stopping services, docker-compose, etc.).
  // Hint: `globalThis` is shared between setup and teardown.

  try {
    await globalThis.__COMPOSE__.down({
      cwd: path.join(__dirname),
      commandOptions: [['--volumes'], ['--remove-orphans'], ['-t', '1']],
      callback: (chunk: Buffer) => {
        console.log('job in progress: ', chunk.toString());
      },
    });

    console.log('Shutdown completed.');
  } catch (err) {
    console.log('Something went wrong during docker compose shutdown:', err.message);
  }

  console.log(globalThis.__TEARDOWN_MESSAGE__);
};
```

This should do the trick and get you started.
Good luck and have fun!